# How to pass string as well as file to be used by open function in C?

Tags: c

I have a function which take filename as input and do "open" and "read" calls to perform some operation. This filename is received via command line argument.
Now, I am trying to make this function generic so that it can receive string as well and perform the same operations. In other way I am passing the content of file directly as string.

I don't know how to stream the string data to the "open" function.
Also, please note that I am restricted to use the open function for file  read.

I tried "pipe" function to stream data to open function, but was not successful.

```
int sopen(char *s) {
    int p[2], ret;
    int fd=-1;
    int len  = strlen(s);

    if (pipe(p) != 0) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Error in creating pipe");
        return -1;
    }

    if ((fd = open(p[0], O_RDONLY)) < 0) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Error in open");
        close(p[0]);
        close(p[1]);
        return -1;
    }

    ret = write(p[1], s, len);
    if (ret != len) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Error in writing to pipe");
        close(p[1]);
        close(fd);
        return -1;

    }
    close(p[1]);

    return fd;
}
```

I expect a file descriptor so that it can be used by the open function, but it is returning -1.

Comment: why `open()` the pipe `p[0]` ? You don't need to call `open()` system call on file descriptors allocated by [pipe](https://linux.die.net/man/2/pipe), do `read()` & `write()` directly. Also use `fork()`.

Comment: From what I have understood, we need to open the stream first before writing on it.

Comment: And that's exactly what `pipe()` does! It opens two streams for you and connects them.

Comment: If the file is small, you might try a much simpler approach: open the file, read it as a whole into a buffer, close the file. Then pass the entire buffer to a separate function accepting a string. In case of processing string data, just call this separate function...

Comment: I wonder why the compiler didn't complain about about `open(p[0], O_RDONLY)`.

Answer (score 1):

As others said, the `pipe()` function returns two descriptors that are already ready-to-use. That means, the `pipe()` already opens them for you. Otherwise it could not guarantee that these are conected to each other.

Remember that you are responsible for closing both of them!

Your whole solution should like something close to this pseudocode below:

```
main
   variable: fileDescriptor

   detect if command line contains a filename, or file content
   if it was a filename
      fileDecriptor = openFile(some arguments...)
   if it was a filecontent
      fileDecriptor = openAndFillPipe(some other arguments...)

   doWhetever(fileDescriptor) // here's the 'operations' on the 'file'

   close(fileDescriptor) // whatever we got, we need to clean it up


openFile(filename)
    // simply: any file-opening will do
    descriptor = open(filename, ...)


openAndFillPipe(filecontent)
    // first, make a pipe: two connected descriptors
    int pairOfDescriptors[2];
    pipe(pairOfDescriptors);

    // [0] is for reading, [1] is for writing
    write(pairOfDescriptors[1], filecontent, ...) // write as if to a file

    close(pairOfDescriptors[1])  // we DONT need the 'write' side anymore

    descriptor = pairOfDescriptors[0] // return the 'read' as if it was a file
```